# Match generics with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to mock the `restTemplate.exchange` method of Spring Rest.

In the same test I have multiple calls which differ only by the return type.

Here are the methods with the mocks I created

First

```
// Original method
restTemplate.exchange(UrlMap.SEARCH + '?' + searchDocsForm.toQueryParams(),
            HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<SearchResultsDTO<SolrDocumentDTO>>() {
            })
// Mock
when(restTemplate.exchange(any(String.class), any(HttpMethod.class), any(), Matchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<SearchResultsDTO<SolrDocumentDTO>>>any())).thenReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<>(searchResultsDTO, HttpStatus.OK));
```

Second

```
// Original method
restTemplate.exchange(UrlMap.ALL_DOCUS_TOPICS,
            HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<SelectItem>>() {
            }).getBody();
// Mock
when(restTemplate.exchange(any(String.class), any(HttpMethod.class), any(), Matchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<SelectItem>>>any())).thenReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<>(selectItems, HttpStatus.OK));
```

The generic parameters of `ParameterizedTypeReference` are not considered by the mock, and the last defined mock wins over the former.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: There would be by creating a custom argument matcher. I know it is possible, however I have never done that so I can't help further, sorry :( (edit: [link](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html))

Comment: FYI, always replace `any(String.class)` with `anyString()`, and similarly for `anyInt()`, `anyFloat()`, etc...  It's simpler, more concise, easire on the eyes, and not subject to type-erasure.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Mockito isn't good at matching generics itself, but your solution is much easier than the general case.

Replace your:

```
Matchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<SearchResultsDTO<SolrDocumentDTO>>>any())
```

with:

```
eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<SearchResultsDTO<SolrDocumentDTO>>() {}))
```

---

First of all, `Matchers.any()` doesn't match type. In Mockito 1.x, `any(Foo.class)` doesn't even match type: `any()` matches [all values, including null and including incorrect types](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any(java.lang.Class)).

> Matches any object, including nulls
>
> This method doesn't do type checks with the given parameter, it is only there to avoid casting in your code. This might however change (type checks could be added) in a future major release.

(Side note: In Mockito 2 and beyond, `any(Foo.class)` has English-like "any Foo" semantics, making it behave much more like `isA(Foo.class)`.)

The generics are helpful to get the right parameter for `exchange` and `thenReturn`, but because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) none of that type information makes it into the CLASS file, let alone the JVM. The only Matcher that asserts the type of its argument is [`isA`](https://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class)), which takes a class literal and won't help you for parameterized types.

You could write a custom Matcher that inspects an argument's type and type parameters, if they aren't subject to erasure, but for your specific case that's not necessary.

Type erasure is the whole reason [ParameterizedTypeReference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html) exists: It captures the generics information into a subclass, where the parameterized type *will not* be erased. This same pattern is used for [TypeToken](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) in Guava or [TypeLiteral](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) in Guice. All of these implementations *describe a parameterized type as an instance*.

Importantly, all of them—including [ParameterizedTypeReference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html)—support `equals` and `hashCode`, so `new ParameterizedTypeReference<A<B>>(){}` equals `new ParameterizedTypeReference<A<B>>(){}` even though the instances are different. [(See the code here.)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/16937c7ce5aa43b495cc04587855da670219eb7a/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.java#L71)

Because references to the same parameterized type are equal, use Mockito's `eq` matcher with a different reference, and things should be fine.