# Spring boot integration test mock bean method with multiple arguments returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I have simple spring boot application with `Controller`,`Service`,`Business` and `Util` classes, so I'm trying to mock the method in `MockUtil` bean which takes four parameters but it returns `null`

**MockMainController**

```
@RestController
public class MockMainController {

@Autowired
private MockBusiness mockBusiness;

@GetMapping("request")
public MockOutput mockRequest() {
    return mockBusiness.businessLogic(new MockInput());

    }

 }
```

**MockBusiness**

```
@Service
public class MockBusiness {

@Autowired
private MockService mockService;

public MockOutput businessLogic(MockInput input) {
    return mockService.serviceLogic(input);
    }

 }
```

**MockService**

```
@Service
public class MockService {

@Autowired
private MockUtil mockUtil;

public MockOutput serviceLogic(MockInput input) {

    ResponseEntity<MockOutput> res = mockUtil.exchange(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(" "), HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<MockOutput>() {
            });
    return res.getBody();

    }

 }
```

**MockUtil**

```
@Component
public class MockUtil {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(UriComponentsBuilder uri, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> entity,
        ParameterizedTypeReference<T> typeReference) {

    try {

        ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toUriString(), method, entity, typeReference);

        return response;
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<T>(ex.getStatusCode());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
         }
     }

 }
```

Below is my simple test class, when ever `mockUtil.exchange` method is called i want to return object based on `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`

**MockControllerTest**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Profile("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MockControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMainController mockMainController;

@MockBean
private MockUtil mockUtil;

@Test
public void controllerTest() {

    given(this.mockUtil.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(new ParameterizedTypeReference<MockOutput>() {
            }.getClass()))).willReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body(new MockOutput("hello", "success")));

    MockOutput output = mockMainController.mockRequest();
    System.out.println(output);

    }

 }
```

By debugging I can see that `mockUtil.exchange` is returning `null`

Comment: Your entire code setup would probably be simpler if you used constructor injection; you would be able to limit the interaction size substantially. (Note also that `RestOperations` exists specifically as a testing facility.)

Comment: I'm just practicing with all the approaches, can you guide me please how to mock `RestOperation` in place of `RestTemplate` @chrylis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the way you match `ParameterizedTypeReference` is not working. It does not match as you expect.

Try the following:

```
given(mockUtil
    .exchange(
        ArgumentMatchers.any(),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(),
        // eq matches to any param of the same generic type
        ArgumentMatchers.eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<MockOutput>(){})))
.willReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body(new MockOutput("hello", "success")));
```

It seems after few tests that if you do not use `eq` Mockito expects the passed `ParameterizedTypeReference` to be the same **instance** as in `given(..)` and with `eq` it just checks that it represents the same generic type.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29670463/6413377) for more details.

Comment: @app Test it yet better before accepting / upvoting. It might be that it just returns null that passes the ANY. So I mean check that it really sees the `ParameterizedTypeReference` by testing it not only with MockOutput but also some other used output and see if you can return different answer with `willReturn` per type.

Comment: ya you are right I have issue with different type, it is always returning the same type for any type

Comment: @app np. try the version with `eq`.